# Psycopg read from dataframe, and persist throwing InvalidTextRepresentation

Tags: pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a pandas dataframe which I want to write to a postgres table in a specific schema.

My postgres table is like

```
CREATE table x (
  pk int8,
  col1 TEXT,
  col2 TEXT,
 ...
)
```

If you have a specific target schema, then you have to use copy_expert. The code I have is

```
buffer = StringIO()
buffer.write(df.to_csv(index=False, header=False, na_rep='NaN'))

buffer.seek(0)
cur = conn.connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
cur.copy_expert("COPY my_schema.my_table FROM STDIN", buffer)
cur.close()
conn.connection.commit()
```

However, I get an error -
`psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for integer: "12, ABC, DEF..."`

So it seems like copy_expert is not able to separate out the fields across commas. How can this be fixed?

Comment: By reading the docs, [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html). See section 'CSV Format'. So `"COPY my_schema.my_table FROM STDIN WITH CSV"`.

Comment: Should have mentioned this is the long way around to what Pandas [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html?highlight=to_sql#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql) provides.

Comment: to_sql is very slow, I am trying to find a faster alternative.